# How do I exclude unchanged fields in Flashback query resultset?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, flashback

Is it possible to exclude unchanged fields in Flashback query resultset?

Consider I have following table

```
create table first_table
(
    id int generated as identity,
    name NVARCHAR2(1024),
    age smallint,
    notebook nclob,
    userpic clob,
    salary float
)
```

If the table has very frequent updates (e.g. on `notebook` field) following versioned query

```
select ROWID, VERSIONS_OPERATION, VERSIONS_STARTSCN, VERSIONS_STARTTIME, VERSIONS_XID, id, name, age, notebook, userpic, salary
from FIRST_TABLE versions between scn 1469193 and 1482882;
```

will pull heavy userpic value for every row even though it's the same.

Can I somehow avoid that and instead get NULLs for unchanged values ?

Comment: `smallint` is an alias to `NUMBER(38)` (which is NOT *small*). `NVARCHAR2/NCLOB` may not be needed if your DB is using character set similar to AL32UTF8.  Pictures are usually stored as `BLOB` (not `CLOB`) along with the mime-type of the picture in a separate column.

Comment: @MichaelKutz Thank you, Michael. This table is just to illustrate the problem. It's not used in production. Is there a way to excluded unchanged fields from versioned response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to excluded unchanged fields from versioned response?

Not really.

Flashback uses the information found in `UNDO`. Flashback Data Archive stores the results from the Log files in a table.

So, you get ALL of the data when you do a Flashback query.

The *common* method is to use `LAG` + `DECODE`.  But, I'm afraid that this will problematic for your `LOB` columns.

Personally, I'd pawn off the problem to the UI (Display Tier).

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that if I pull data directly from history tables LOB columns have NULL value. Could you please point me to the documentation where this behavior is explained?